# How to find what processes are eating up battery?

Tags: battery, microsoft-surface

I have a new Surface 3 (a little over a month old) and in the past few weeks I have noticed that the battery drains very quickly and does not charge when I am using it if it is plugged in.  After testing a few things I am pretty sure that there is some background something that is using up my battery, and it is not a problem with my battery.

I have tried watching resource monitor but I haven't noticed any unusual CPU spikes or usage.  **So what other methods can I use to diagnose what is eating up my battery?**

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for the [Battery Usage Report](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31440-battery-usage-report-generate-windows-8-a.html).

> Open Command Prompt and enter:
>
> `powercfg /batteryreport /output "<enter path here>\battery_report.html"`
>
> Find the battery_report.html file output and open it.

This will not show you which programs are using the battery, just statistics. You can find out what is using it if the laptop is sleeping using [Sleep Study](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2014/06/26/sleep-study-diagnose-whats-draining-your-battery-while-the-system-sleeps/) which is another type of battery report built-in to Windows 8.

To monitor the programs using the most battery while awake, you would probably need a separate piece of software.